# Where to find a template or script with frame on the left side(list of articleHeadlines) and on the right side the content

Tags: web-development, looking-for-a-script, cms

I am looking for something like the following:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/004t00000009000000/

On the left side i want to have/create in some admintool categeries, subcategories and add names/links to the articles on the right side. So when i click on one of the articles/links, i would see the content on the right side.

Is there any script or template or whatever that would allow me that?

edit: to be specific:

- in admin area i would create categories and subcategories. In each of the subcategories i would be able to create an article.
- When i click at that article, i want to see that article on the right side of screen. It would be awesome if visitors would be able to post comments to that article.
- it does not matter what CMS that would be
- it looks like some kind of a treestructure

Comment: How about using a WordPress plugin for tree structure? See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/

  You're looking for a tree structure theme. Google it + name of a CMS.

Comment: this is kinda the direction i want to go. Have to give a closer look. Are there any other plugin oder templates too?

Comment: Well, are you going to use the template on a CMS? If so, what CMS it is?

Comment: to be honest, it would not matter if it is drupal, wordpress, joomla, typo3 if i could get that functionality. i would learn it.